# Norm of a function on a set of measure $0$ and convergence of a sequence on a set of finite measure

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a measurable set with finite Lebesgue measure, $\{f_n\}_{n∈N}$ be a sequence of measurable functions $f_n : E → \mathbb{R}$, bounded in $L^p(E)$ for $p>1$, and pointwise converging to $f : E → \mathbb{R}$ almost everywhere.

Since the sequence converge almost everywhere, consider the set $N_0$ of measure zero where the sequence does not converge, and $E\setminus N_0$ where the sequence converge. By Egorov theorem the sequence converges to $f$ uniformly on $E\setminus N_0$.

Study the convergence in $L^q(E)$ for $q∈(1,p)$:
\begin{align*}
||f_n-f||_{L^q(E)}&\le||f_n-f||_{L^q(N_0)}+||f_n-f||_{L^q(E\setminus N_0)} \\ &\le ||f_n||_{L^q(N_0)}+||f||_{L^q(N_0)}+||f_n-f||_{L^q(E\setminus N_0)}
\end{align*}
I'd say that the first two norms in the rhs are $0$ since they are integrals on a set of measure $0$, but wouldn't this mean that $f_n$ converge to $f$ on $N_0$? But it is a contraddiction because we defined it as the set where the sequence does not converge, isn'it?

Moreover how to compute or bound the last norm on the rhs?

Comment: Egorov's Theorem does not say that the sequence converges uniformly on $N$. Your attempt to prove $L^{q}$ convergence completely fails.

Comment: I didnt say that Egorov theorem implies convergence on $N_0$, I obtain that from my assumptions on the values of the norm. I know I'm wrong, that's why I'm here asking for help.

Comment: The result you are trying ti prove is true but it has a lengthy argument. Are you familiar with uniform integrability? You have to  show that $\{|f_n|^{q}\}$ (and hence $\{|f_n-f|^{q}\}$) is uniformly integrable from which $L^{q}$ convergence follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we note that Fatou's Lemma implies that $f \in L^p(E)$. Now, we apply Egorov and obtain that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a measurable set $M_\varepsilon$ with $\mu(M_\varepsilon) \le \varepsilon$
such that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $E \setminus M_\varepsilon$.
Now, we use the triangle inequality to get
$$\|f_n - f\|_{L^q(E)}
 \le \|f_n - f\|_{L^q(M_\varepsilon)} + \|f_n-f\|_{L^q(E\setminus M_\varepsilon)}
 \le \|f_n - f\|_{L^q(M_\varepsilon)} + \|f_n-f\|_{L^\infty(E\setminus M_\varepsilon)} \, \mu(E)^{1/q}.$$
In the first addend, we can use Hölders inequality
(with $1/q = 1/p + 1/r$ for some $r \in (1,\infty)$) to obtain
$$\|f_n - f\|_{L^q(M_\varepsilon)} \le \|1\|_{L^r(M_\varepsilon)} \, \|f_n - f\|_{L^p(M_\varepsilon)} \le \varepsilon^{1/r} \, (\|f_n\|_{L^p(M_\varepsilon)}+\|f\|_{L^p(M_\varepsilon)} \le C \, \varepsilon^{1/r}.$$
Thus,
$$\|f_n - f\|_{L^q(E)}
\le
C \, \varepsilon^{1/r}
 + \|f_n-f\|_{L^\infty(E\setminus M_\varepsilon)} \, \mu(E)^{1/q}.$$
Hence, we can choose $N$ (depending on $\varepsilon$) large enough such that
$$\|f_n - f\|_{L^q(E)}
\le
2 \, C \, \varepsilon^{1/r}
\qquad\forall n \ge N.$$

Hence, $f_n \to f$ in $L^q(E)$. Note that this argument also works for $q = 1$.

Comment: This proof is wrong. The hypothesis only gives pointwise convergence and boundedness of $L^{p}$ norms. How did you conclude that $f_n \to f$ i n $L^{p}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Ups, I misread the assumptions. I will fix it.

Comment: @gerw In the first line why did you write that the $L^q(E)$ norm of $f_n-f$ is less or equal than the sum of $L^q$ and $L^p$ norms? Should not be both $L^q$ norms?

Comment: @gerw Moreover, how can you write that the second addend (first line) is less or equal than the $L^\infty(E\setminus M_\varepsilon)$ norm times the measure of the whole set $E$ power $1/q$?

Comment: @soundwave: Yes, both should be $L^q$ norms (changed). The second inequality using the simple bound $\|g\|_{L^q(C)}^q \le \int_C |g|^q \, \mathrm{d}x \le \|g\|_{L^\infty(C)}^q \, \mu(C)$ together with $\mu(E\setminus M_\varepsilon) \le \mu(E)$.

Comment: @gerw Thank you very much gerw you helped a lot, could you please explain why $\int_C|g|^q\le||g||_{L^{\infty}(C)}^q\mu(C)$ ? I guess, the $L^{\infty}(C)$ norm is the maximum of $g$ on $C$, are you saying that the product of this max with the measure of $C$ is larger or equal than the $L^q(C)$ norm power $q$ of $g$ ? If so, why we have such an inequality?

Comment: Because $|g(x)|^q \le \|g\|_{L^\infty(C)}^q$ for a.a. $x \in C$. Now you integrate this inequality over $C$. The right-hand side is a constant, hence it is multiplied by the measure of $C$.

Comment: @gerw thank you very much helped a lot